# "I've been inside you; there's not so much there as you think."

Tags: blade-runner-2049

Says the replicant hooker to Joi. There is much to consider but one question is, does a person "inside" a hologram experience anything at all? She could have been being sarcastic -- they both know that there is literally nothing inside of her, at least that the hooker could experience.

But perhaps there is something that the hooker *could* feel. We saw Joi light a cigarette which may of course be a trick of the emitter: it has lasers and can focus them to create heat. Or maybe the holograms have some sort of actual physical presence although I see no evidence for this.

Comment: Real world technology https://www.slashgear.com/sound-sculpting-creates-holograms-you-can-feel-02357996/ and
  https://youtu.be/tzWP-NL3Lck around 2 minute mark

Comment: @lucasbachmann: interesting, maybe when Joi touches you there is a physical sensation.